# Making a variable transformer "safe"

Tags: safety

I have a US mains voltage variable transformer that I am using as a variable DC power supply for some robotics experiments I am doing.

I have built the below circuit in a metal box that is grounded.

The problem I am finding is that when I accidentally touch the DC at the same time as I touch the case or switch and (probably obviously) get a shock.

Is there any way to make this circuit safe?

Do  I need to put a 1:1 transformer (isolation transformer) on the output of the variable transformer so I can ground the DC? Is there another way to ground the DC to earth ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDETCV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Put the isolation transformer on the *input* side of the Variac.

Comment: @DaveTweed isn't that going to still have the DC rectifier cause an offset between ground and DC-?

Comment: The rectifier causes an offset between ground and DC anyways. One that changes constantly.

Comment: You getting zapped anyway by touching DC output and ground. Current flow going through two diodes and your body. Halfwaves, less power, but still harmfull. Isolation still needs, like regular power from receptacle.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzPvRJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

A first basic step would be to minimise risk by ensuring that the variable transformer common point to neutral and not live. (See Figure 1a.) This will minimise the risk of electrocution depending on the output voltage.

The isolation transformer should be placed on the primary and the circuit connected as shown in Figure 1b.

Comment: Except that the terminal of the Variac should NOT be grounded. Ground the DC- output terminal instead.

Comment: @DaveTweed, it depends on what's required. But you're right that the normal approach would be to ground the DC-. Circuit modified.

Comment: What kind of protection device grounding DC can trigger? By "ground" name could be different things. Supposevely, in second schematic it is not "Protective Earth" .

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, "ground" in AC mains is NOT project common-rail 0V.  "Ground" is a safety shield exclusively and must be 100% isolated from neutral *and* hot.   AC mains power is wired as an *isolated system*, with neutral and ground fully isolated except for ***one*** deliberate equipotential bond at the demarcation point between utility and building service (first disconnect point past meter).

You need to fuse and switch the *hot* wire.  *"Wait, polarization? In AC?"*  Yes.  The aforementioned bond in the building service pegs one of the energized wires to quite near ground voltage (within 3 volts).  This is a live conductor, but it's "less Dangerous" so it's called Neutral.  We call that polarization for some reason.

We then do the more dodgy things (like omit breakers or switches) with neutral instead of hot.

As Transistor discusses, your variac's jumper between F1 and SW1 is a violation of NEC and the "UL White Book" design standards.  The hot wire is biased 120VAC from ground.  Because of that jumper, your variable output is biased [120VAC; 120VAC - variac voltage] from ground.  NOT GOOD!   If you must have that jumper, it must be on the neutral side, resulting in a bias from ground of [0V; variac voltage] for the two outputs.

But even so, you must design for the possibility of someone using a cheater and plugging the thing in upside-down.  That is why the jumper needs to go away (since the transformer provides isolation, why defeat it????)

Really, if you're building this as a small-scale project, and you're looking for a "Get out of jail free" card, the right answer is GFCI protection built right into your unit.  Any of:

- use a cord with a GFCI in it; found in air conditioners and hair dryers.  (which are 1500-1800W, buy a $16 hair dryer, SNIP! and you have a cord GFCI).
- Use a DIN-rail or chassis mount GFCI breaker (doubling as a switch).
- Put an opening sized for a Decora receptacle (sized like a *Raco 808C* domed cover, *or simply using* same domed cover).  Mount a GFCI receptacle in that opening.  *Voilà: Convenience outlets!*
- Same, but use a "GFCI Switch" such as a Legrand 2087WCCD4.

GFCI is generally more reliable than grounding at reducing shock risk.

You could also use an isolation transformer, but I would put it on the supply side, after the power switch which appears to be missing from your drawing.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. A 20A isolation transformer runs ~$500, a GFCI wall adapter (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-Wall-Adapter-GFCI-04-00106/303137134) is $20.